# Java obfuscation: remove exception messages

Tags: java, exception, obfuscation

I do obfuscation of my Java code before delivery (currently using ProGuard).

When I "decompile" the obfuscated byte code, obviously all strings are not obfuscated. This is also true for messages in exceptions. These exception messages give the reader a lot of information to understand the code. Like:

```
if(a == null){
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("SuperSecretObject cannot be null");
}
```

Is it possible, using ProGuard or another tool to compile while removing all exception message strings?

Else, can you recommend other methods to hide strings which are not functionally necessary?

Comment: Removing exception messages with change the code behaviour.

Comment: You can move exception messages to a file outside the code, but even then one can always refer to those messages.

Comment: @Sudhanshu good idea: I could use a Properties which returns "" when a key isn't found. The properties would be populated only on test installation which should have the exception messages.

Answer (score 1):

For example you could use

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException(SuperSecretObject.class.getName() + " cannot be null");
```

Then the the obfuscator can also replace the class name with the obfuscated one.